# TeXstudio select whole line

Tags: macros, shortcuts, latex

I like the CTRL+L shortcut in SublimeText and would like to have it in TeXstudio, too.

**What it does:**
It selects the whole current line and places the cursor at the beginning of the next line. That way I can copy the line (including the trailing newline), delete it, cut it, ...

But I can't find a way to configure it. There is no such option in the "Shortcuts" list and I can't find a command for selecting text with a javascript-macro (http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#SECTION33)

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

On a Mac:

- Put the cursor at the beginning of the line which you want to select.
- Hold the `SHIFT+OPTION` buttons.
- Push the `Down Arrow` key once or twice to select the whole line.

On a PC:

- Similar approach will work - use `CTRL` instead of `OPTION` key.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a workaroud:

On a line hit <kbd>End</kbd> after that hold <kbd>shift</kbd> and press <kbd>Home</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

I'm certainly late at this thread, but in TeXStudio 2.12 this option is available in the Menu.

`Edit > Selection > Expand Selection to Line`

It has the default shortcut as `Ctrl + L` in Linux, but it is nonetheless configurable in

`Options > Configure TeXStudio > Shortcuts > Edit > Selection > Expand Selection to Line`

[You can check the shortcut in this print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqzOt.png)

... perharps the answer is useful as future reference.

Answer (score 0):

I'm certainly late at this thread too, but a useful script for TeXStudio that lets you rapidly copy, cut and paste whole line is here:
https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/wiki/Scripts/#copy-paste-lines
Enjoy!